# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, php-7

I have been checking all questions related, but the solutions did not solve the issue i'm getting.

I'm trying to set a EC2 instance, installing php7.0, mysql, composer, cloned the repository, etc..

This EC2 instance is a Centos 6.5.

But when :

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(263): Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/var/www/html/T...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/var/www/html/T...')
#2 /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(72): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->load('web.xml')
#3 /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(59): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Dependen in /var/www/html/TFM_RedSocialMusical/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 52
```

Well, searching similar questions, the purposed solution is:

```
sudo yum install php-xml
```

I'm getting:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.heanet.ie
 * epel: ftp.heanet.ie
 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.24)(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.22)(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.18)(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.13)(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11)(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1()(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexslt.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-xml-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.el6_3.1 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.20-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0.20
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-json-7.0.20-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 conflicts php-json < 7.0.20
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
Error: php70u-json conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I Have installed the php70u-common , but how can avoid this conflict with php-common-5.3.3-49?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See how there's `php70u-common` and `php70u-json`? There's probably a package called `php70u-xml`.

Comment: Damn! I had tried with php70-xml, php7.0-xml with no luck! It worked @ceejayoz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on the comments, installing `php70u-xml` solved the problem.

Comment: For me it say's: unable to locate package php70u-xml.

Comment: Are you using centos? Ubuntu? May be it depends on the version you are using... check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998900/i-get-the-unable-to-locate-package-message-when-trying-to-install-php-xml-rss

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu. Thanks. I will check it. Not some solution but yesterday I reinstalled PHP (locally) and it worked. I think the problem was some conflict with diff PHP versions. Not so experience in that. I had 5.6 and 7.2. Fresh installed 7.0.